# Qt6 with Cmake submodule ReferenceError

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qt6

I have a QT6 Qml with a Cmake File like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(appTEST VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Gui Qml Quick REQUIRED)



set(CPPSOURCES
    ...)
set(CPPHEADERS
    ...)

qt_add_executable(appTEST 
    main.cpp
    ${CPPSOURCES}
    ${CPPHEADERS}
)

target_link_libraries(appTEST 
    PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::Qml)

install(TARGETS appTEST 
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

qt6_add_qml_module(appTEST 
    URI "Main"
    VERSION 1.0
    NO_PLUGIN
    QML_FILES main.qml
)

add_subdirectory(content)
add_subdirectory(imports)


target_link_libraries(appTEST PRIVATE
    contentplugin
    impplugin

)
```

and the `content` module:

```
    qt_add_library(content STATIC)
    qt6_add_qml_module(content
        URI "content"
        VERSION 1.0
        QML_FILES
        ...
    )
```

and `imp` module :

```
set_source_files_properties(Constants.qml
    PROPERTIES
        QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE true
)
...



qt_add_library(imp STATIC)
qt6_add_qml_module(imp 
    URI "imp" 
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        Constants.qml
        ...
)
```

with the `constatnt.qml` marked as a Singleton like this:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 6.3

QtObject {
    ...
}
```

so I expect to be able to import imp on any page and have access to `constatnt.qml` properties.
but in run time get this error

> ReferenceError: Constants is not defined

note tath I tried to adopt the structure from `Qt Design Studio` default project template.

Comment: can you check if there is a qmldir file? (probably somewhere in the build folder). I'm not knowledgable on the Qt6, but maybe this gives some insights

Comment: yes there is a qmldir file in build directory of modules @Amfasis

Comment: Does it contain a line for `Constants`?

Comment: yes it does.it atcualy contains the 3 singletone files I added @Amfasis

Comment: Including the 'singleton' keyword there as well? If no, seems like a bug in the cmake module; if yes, I don't know

Comment: yes this is the exact line ```singleton Constants 1.0 Constants.qml``` @Amfasis